# Outlook VSTO Addin

Tags: c#, vsto

I'm currently working on add in to outlook but face a problem my requirement is to add feature that is similar to spell checking (program will underline some of the text in real time). Is that even possible in vsto ? any material is appreciated i've searched for answer online - without any success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integration you need would not be with VSTO or the Outlook Object Model, but rather mainly with the Word Object Model (WOM).  Outlook users Word to render HTML formatted messages and provides access to the email as if it is a Word document, via the Inspector.WordEditor property which returns a Word.Document object.

So you can use WOM to format the body content as you see fit. However, there are no real-time events for hooking into changes of the message body as they occur.  You will need to use either timers or low-level keyboard hooks to capture the changes that the user is making.